# Haskell: Why is the pattern matching not exhaustive even if it compiles and executes?

Tags: haskell

Learning Haskell, bit confused about the code hint here:

```
getMax :: [Int] -> Int
getMax [a] = a
getMax (a:b:as) = getMax ((if a >= b then a else b):as)
```

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘getMax’: Patterns not matched: []
```

It works and finds the max of eg `[5, 2, 6]`. Does it need a pattern for the empty list? What's a reasonable return value then? Zero? Can I return something like `undefined`?

Comment: Well the compiler hints that here you do not have a case for the emtpy list.

Comment: OK, then I'll add `[] = 0`, but i'd rather return something like an exception.

Comment: Don't return `0`. As you say, it's better to return `error "getMax: empty list`. A crash is easier to debug than a wrong value. Alternatively, make `getMax :: [Int] -> Maybe Int` so that you can return `Nothing` when the list is empty, and `Just theMax` otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it need a pattern for the empty list?

Not *per se*, since it is just a warning. As long as you never pass it an empty list, it will here work fine. But it is up to you to check that, and you can never be sure that somehow an empty list will be passed.

> What's a reasonable return value then? Zero? Can I return something like `undefined`?

That is of course up to you to decide. You probably might want to make a distinction between the result of an empty list an a non-empty list. In Haskell usually therefore a `Maybe` is used. For example:

```
getMax :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
getMax [] = Nothing
getMax [a] = Just a
getMax (a:b:as) = getMax ((if a >= b then a else b):as)
```

or you can change the input, such that it is for example impossible to pass a non-empty list. We can here work with two parameters, so the signature is then `getMax :: Int -> [Int] -> Int`. Here the first parameter is the "head" of the list, and the second is the tail of the list:

```
getMax :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
getMax a [] = a
getMax a (b:as) = getMax (if a >= b then a else b) as
```

Using `undefined` is usually not a good idea. Yes than we no longer have a non-exhaustive pattern, but evaluating the `undefined` will raise an error. So it is only trading one problem for another one.

Answer (score 3):

If your function can only work on non-empty lists, then you should indicate that in its type:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))

getMax :: NonEmpty Int -> Int
getMax (a:|[]) = a
getMax (a:|b:as) = getMax ((if a >= b then a else b):|as)
```

This is strictly more useful than using `Maybe` directly, as then you don't have to handle a `Nothing` that can never happen if you're sure the list isn't empty. (And if you're not sure, then you can call `fmap getMax . nonEmpty` instead, which is exactly the same as `getMax` would be had it used `Maybe`.)